# Input parameter in Django method

Tags: python, ios, django, web-services

I'm new in working with python and Django. I want to write a web service in django that receives some input parameteres and return back a response. This web service is supposed to get called from an iOS app. I wrote the below method but I'm not sure about having input parameter(ccId). Should I read the input parameter from request object? If so can you please give me some example code.

```
def get_clients(request, ccId):    
    lstClients = Patients.objects.filter(cr=ccId)    
    data = serializers.serialize("json", lstClients, fields=('tel',))
    return http.HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could read the parameters from the request object:

```
def get_clients(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ccId = request.GET['ccId']
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        ccId = request.POST['ccId']

    lstClients = Patients.objects.filter(cr=ccId)    
    data = serializers.serialize("json", lstClients, fields=('tel',))
    return http.HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Maybe you will need to convert the object received to its appropriate type. Something like: `ccId = int(request.GET['ccId']`.

Take a look at Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects